# Implementing interface C#

Tags: c#, interface

I'm not new to C#, but I have found a behavior that is a little puzzling.

I have an interface

```
public interface IApplicationPage
{
    Person ThePerson { get; set;  }
    Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

I implement the interface on a page

```
public partial class tripapplication2 : System.Web.UI.Page, IApplicationPage
{
    Person IApplicationPage.ThePerson { get; set; }
    Application IApplicationPage.IApplicationPage.Application { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I attempt to reference ThePerson in the page itself I need to jump through hoops.  For example.

1) ThePerson.Birthday

Gives an error saying "The name 'ThePerson' does not exist in the current context."

2) ((IMissionTripApplicationPage)this).ThePerson.Birthday

This works, but it looks awful.

Is there a better way to reference the implemented properties?

Comment: Can you show the specific code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you left a line out in your sample.  I believe the ThePerson line in the implementation should read

```
Person IApplicationPage.ThePerson { get; set; }
```

This type of implementation is known as an explicit interface implementation.  This means the member will only be viewable when the object is seen through a reference of the interface type.

If you want the member to be viewable through a concrete type reference, make it public and remove the explicit implementation

```
public Person ThePerson { get; set; }
```

Comment: Aboslutely right, I did leave out the line!  (careless copying).  Thanks Jared.

Answer (score 3):

Implement them as public properties:

```
public partial class tripapplication2 : System.Web.UI.Page, IApplicationPage
{
    public Person ThePerson { get; set; }
    public Application IApplicationPage.Application { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

Question now edited to show these were implemented originally as explicit. So, I should restate mine as implement them as public rather than explicit implementations of the properties.

Comment: You cannot make explicit implementations public (Application IApplicationPage.Application is explicit!)

Comment: It wasn't explicit when I answered. Quite right though of course.