# How to implement interface

Tags: c#, wpf, interface

I want to change my code, also I want to use Interfaces so if someone wants a future so it could be easily implemented, without changing too much code.

So I successfully implemented my interface IPalindromeChecker. But the problem is in MainWindow now. **So I'm not sure but I would make another Interface and with `public void Output(string text)` method**. I've tried adding a method in IPalindromeChecker `public void Output(string text)` but it didn't work.

```
 interface ICheckPalindrome
    {
        bool IsPalindrome(string text);
    }
```

```
public class PalindromeChecker : ICheckPalindrome
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for checking if the word/text is a palindrome.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPalindrome(string text)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = text.Length - 1;

            while (true)
            {
                if (min > max)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                char a = text[min];
                char b = text[max];

                if (a != b)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                min++;
                max--;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lblInput.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
            lblResult.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
            lblTitel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// User input and checking the input if the word a palindrome is.
        /// </summary>
        private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = InputText.Text;

            bool isPalindrome = TextChecker.PalindromeChecker(text); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM

            OutputText.Text = text + (isPalindrome ? " is a palindrome" : " is NOT a palindrome");

            if (InputText.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                OutputText.Clear();
            }
        }
```

```
 public class PalindromeChecker : ICheckPalindrome
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for checking if the word/text is a palindrome.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPalindrome(string text)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = text.Length - 1;

            while (true)
            {
                if (min > max)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                char a = text[min];
                char b = text[max];

                if (a != b)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                min++;
                max--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `TextChecker.PalindromeChecker`? How are you using the interface in `MainWindow`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: If you want to be able to easily switch the implementation of `IsPalindrome` without modifying the `MainWindow`, it shouldn't be static. This would defeat the purpose of using an interface in this first place. And since it implements the `ICheckPalindrome` interface, it cannot be static.

Comment: TBH, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160069/implementing-interface-c-sharp) question along with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1160090/1797425) answer...

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what `TextChecker.PalindromeChecker` is but if you want to be able to switch implementations of the `ICheckPalindrome` interface without having to modify your `MainWindow`, you should inject the window with an implementation of `ICheckPalindrome` at runtime and write your code against the interface.

You could for example use a property to do this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblInput.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        lblResult.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        lblTitel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;

        //use the PalindromeChecker as the default implementation
        PalindromeChecker = new PalindromeChecker();

    }

    public ICheckPalindrome PalindromeChecker { get; set; } //<--

    private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = InputText.Text;

        bool isPalindrome = PalindromeChecker.IsPalindrome(text);

        OutputText.Text = text + (isPalindrome ? " is a palindrome" : " is NOT a palindrome");

        if (InputText.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            OutputText.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Switching to another implementation is then as simple as just setting the `PalindromeChecker` property of the `MainWindow` to an instance of another class that implements the same `ICheckPalindrome` interface.

Comment: Hi, PalindromeChecker is method where I check if the word is Palindrome, and I used ``TextChecker.PalindromeChecker`` to call the method. I can't set the instance ``public ICheckPalindrome PalindromeChecker { get; set; } //<--``

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you define a property?